# Create polynomial with given coefficients

Tags: python, polynomials, coefficients

I want to create a polynomial with given coefficients in Python but without numpy or any similar library.

For example, if input is (12,2,5,3) which is a0,a1,a2,a3 respectively, expected output is 12+2x+5x^2+3x^3.

```
def polynomial(p,x):
    return sum((a*x**i for i,a in enumerate(p)))

polynomial(([12,2,5,3]),x)
```

I tried the code above but I got an error message, naturally, that x is not defined. What is wrong with the code or is there a problem with running it?

Answer (score 1):

The `x is not defined` error is not from your function, but where you call the function. You need to call the function with an actual number:

```
poly = polynomial([12, 2, 5, 3], 5)
```

Also, you may want to consider making `poly` a function that returns a function; namely, so that you could use the syntax:

```
poly = polynomial([12, 2, 5, 3])
poly(5) # poly evaluated at 5
poly(10) # poly evaluated at 10
```

To do that, use this syntax:

```
def polynomial(p):
    return lambda x: sum(a*x**i for i, a in enumerate(p))
```

Comment: Shouldn't `a*x**(len(p)-i)` be either `a*x**(len(p)-i-1)` or ``a*x**i in case you want to preserve the same order as in the original post?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's what you're looking for, but you can use `sympy` for symbolic language, something like this:

```
from sympy import symbols

def polynomial(coefs,var):
    x = symbols(var)
    return [c*x for c in coefs]

>> polynomial([1,2,3,4],'x')
[x, 2*x, 3*x, 4*x]
```

If it does not solve your problem, it can give you an idea of how to solve it.

Regards

Comment: Also with sympy you'd need to return sum instead of a list and use powers for x. Something like `sympy.Sum([c*x**i for i,c in enumerate(coefs)])`.

Comment: That is true and complements my suggestion, thank you. However, how to use the proposed solutions depends on what the friend who asked the question really needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of `map`:

```
def polynomial(p, x):
  return sum(map(lambda (i, c): c * pow(x, i), enumerate(p)))
```